# getAttachmentContentAsync does not return anything

Tags: outlook, office365, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I've read the documentation over on: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.messagecompose?view=outlook-js-preview&preserve-view=true#getComposeTypeAsync_options__callback_ , but nothing has been returned. Not even error messages. It doesn't return anything at all. The code i've used is below:

```
var item = Office.context.mailbox.item;
var options = {asyncContext: {currentItem: item}};
item.getAttachmentsAsync(options, callback);

function callback(result) {
    if (result.value.length > 0) {
        for (i = 0 ; i < result.value.length ; i++) {
            result.asyncContext.currentItem.getAttachmentContentAsync(result.value[i].id, handleAttachmentsCallback);
        }
    }
}

function handleAttachmentsCallback(result) {
    // Parse string to be a url, an .eml file, a base64-encoded string, or an .icalendar file.
    switch (result.value.format) {
        case Office.MailboxEnums.AttachmentContentFormat.Base64:
            // Handle file attachment.
            console.log(result.value.content);
            break;
        case Office.MailboxEnums.AttachmentContentFormat.Eml:
            // Handle email item attachment.
            console.log("Attachment is a message.");
            break;
        case Office.MailboxEnums.AttachmentContentFormat.ICalendar:
            // Handle .icalender attachment.
            console.log("Attachment is a calendar item.");
            break;
        case Office.MailboxEnums.AttachmentContentFormat.Url:
            // Handle cloud attachment.
            console.log("Attachment is a cloud attachment.");
            break;
        default:
            // Handle attachment formats that are not supported.
    }
}
```

I have inserted the code for the MessageCompose form and I know that it requires the v1.8 API. I have tested other methods such as getAttachmentsAsync(options, callback) and they work as expected.
As a test, I have been using console logs at specific points where the code works up to. The console outputs the result of callback(result) as *OSF.DDA.AsyncResult* where *status=succeeded*. However, it displays *"This value was evaluated upon first expanding. It may have changed since then."* and it won't allow me to inspect the Object when you click expand.

Additionally logging result.value[i] in callback works as well, with the same issue where I cant expand the object for more details.

Why won't getAttachmentContentAsync return anything?

Comment: Which Outlook client are you using? Are you using the web client in a browser, or the rich native Windows Desktop client or Mac Outlook?

Comment: I am using Office 365 Outlook Web (web client) in a browser

Comment: We are not able to reproduce this issue .Can you please share repro video??